# SQL Server - date iterations using macros?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know if it is possible to do this in a simpler way: I am trying to calculate the number of earned days between 2 time periods (for many different time periods) - I have literally copied and pasted the same set a number of times. I was able to do this in SAS but don't know how in SQL Server! Thanks

```
declare   @StartDate1 datetime, @StartDate2 datetime, @StartDate3 datetime, @StartDate4 datetime, @StartDate5 datetime
 set @StartDate1 = '01-JAN-2007'
 set @StartDate2 = '01-APR-2007'
 set @StartDate3 = '01-JUN-2007'
 set @StartDate4 = '01-OCT-2007'
 set @StartDate5 = '01-JAN-2008'

if object_id('TA_agreementEarnings_q1_2007') is not null drop table TA_agreementEarnings_q1_2007;
select case when warrantyStartDate <= @startDate1 and enddate >= dateadd(m,3,@startDate1) then datediff(dd, @startDate1, dateadd(m,3,@startDate1))
             when warrantyStartDate <= @startDate1 and enddate between dateadd(m,3,@startDate1) and @startDate1 then datediff(dd, enddate, @startDate1)
             when warrantyStartDate between @startDate1 and dateadd(m,3,@startDate1) and enddate >= dateadd(m,3,@startDate1) then datediff(dd, warrantyStartDate, dateadd(m,3,@startDate1))
             when warrantyStartDate between @startDate1 and dateadd(m,3,@startDate1) and enddate between @startDate1 and dateadd(m,3,@startDate1) then datediff(dd, warrantyStartDate, enddate)
             else 0 end as q1_2007 , vehicleNo, agreeNo, riskclass
into TA_agreementEarnings_q1_2007
from TA_agreementEarnings a

if object_id('TA_agreementEarnings_q2_2007') is not null drop table TA_agreementEarnings_q2_2007;
select case when warrantyStartDate <= @startDate2 and enddate >= dateadd(m,3,@startDate2) then datediff(dd, @startDate2, dateadd(m,3,@startDate2))
             when warrantyStartDate <= @startDate2 and enddate between dateadd(m,3,@startDate2) and @startDate2 then datediff(dd, enddate, @startDate2)
             when warrantyStartDate between @startDate2 and dateadd(m,3,@startDate2) and enddate >= dateadd(m,3,@startDate2) then datediff(dd, warrantyStartDate, dateadd(m,3,@startDate2))
             when warrantyStartDate between @startDate2 and dateadd(m,3,@startDate2) and enddate between @startDate2 and dateadd(m,3,@startDate2) then datediff(dd, warrantyStartDate, enddate)
             else 0 end as q2_2007 , vehicleNo, agreeNo, riskclass
 into TA_agreementEarnings_q2_2007
 from TA_agreementEarnings a
```

Repeated about 30 times!

Thanks for any help

Comment: No you can't use macros, however if you generate a table with all dates and resultant values then you can just look up the result with a join. What you're essentially doing it converting a procedural solution into a data based solution.

Comment: no its the iteration part that I want to streamline - that doesn't help with the part of having the same step written out 30 times.

Comment: Yes it does if you're prepared to adopt a set based approach. If you follow the answer I gave below you can see that it can generate all the date for all the quarters at the same time - say to a temp table. Then you can either cursor or whatever you choose to generate mini tables like TA_agreementEarnings_q2_2007 if that what you need. Perhaps you can use views instead? Either what I'm suggesting is that you do all the data in one hit if you can and then filter as opposed to doing it in bitty way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to generate a look up table based on ranges and then join to this table.

```
DROP TABLE TA_agreementEarnings;
CREATE TABLE TA_agreementEarnings (warrantyStartDate datetime, vehicleNo int, agreeNo int, riskclass nvarchar(10));
INSERT INTO TA_agreementEarnings (warrantyStartDate, vehicleNo, agreeNo, riskclass)  VALUES ('2007-01-20', 1, 2, 'bad!!');

;WITH 
AllDates as
(
    SELECT CAST('1900-01-01' AS DATETIME) TheDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TheDate + 1
    FROM    AllDates   
    WHERE   TheDate + 1 < '2050-12-31'
),
Ranges AS
(
    SELECT '2007-01-01' StartRange, '2007-03-31' EndRange UNION ALL
    SELECT '2007-04-01', '2007-05-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2007-06-01', '2007-09-30' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2007-10-01', '2007-12-31' 
),
RangedDates AS 
(
    SELECT
        A.TheDate, 
        R.StartRange,
        R.EndRange,
        DATEDIFF(dd, A.TheDate, DATEADD(M,3,R.StartRange)) CalculatedDateDiff
    FROM 
        AllDates A
        INNER JOIN  Ranges R ON A.TheDate BETWEEN R.StartRange AND R.EndRange
)
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    TA_agreementEarnings E
    LEFT JOIN RangedDates D ON D.TheDate = E.warrantyStartDate
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

here I create set of all dates between 1900 & 2050, and INNER JOIN it it to the set of ranges which are from your startdate variables. This limits the set to the Ranges.

Next I create a calculated column on each row of the set, this essentially gives me a look up value for any value in TheDate.

Finally I join this resultant set to the target table on the warrantyDate = TheDate (which is very fast btw) and I can get any column output from the RangedDates dataset. So there is not need to compare the warranty date with multiple ranges.

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    TA_agreementEarnings E
    LEFT JOIN RangedDates D ON D.TheDate = E.warrantyStartDate;
```

Which gives this result:

[image]

Note that I used a LEFT JOIN in the final query - this will return nulls for the RangedDates  where there is no range to match the warrantyDate. This may be important to you or not.

---

For your case you probably need to tweak the calculations, and the perhaps add new calculated columns based on years/tables etc. But in essence your converting the calculation from being procedural and in line to being declarative and looked up.